# How to create multiple username and password for Gitea using bash script

Tags: bash, github

I am trying to automate the process of creating usernames and passwords for new employees. The domain is **git.company.com** I have the following code which can create a single user:

```
#!/bin/sh

# after `=` type the user account and password you wish to create respectively

user=your_selected_account_name
password=your_supersecret_password

adduser --quiet --disabled-password --shell /bin/bash --home /home/$user --gecos "User" $user

# set password
echo "$user:$password" | chpasswd

echo User: $user has been created with password: $password

#SCRIPT END
```

To create multiple users I most likely will be using a csv file with their details. How can I use that to create multiple usernames and passwords? By the way, We have APIs to create the users as well. If you want to use that then it is fine as well. I am going to be using AWS Cloudshell to run the script.

Comment: I thought it is obvious: You already have a script which takes as parameter username and password and creates the user entry. You can then loop over the CSV file and for each line in the CSV file invoke that script. Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: I tried the above script for a single user and it is showing me a username or password not correct error when logging in with it

Comment: Then the problem is not with processing the CSV file, but to fix the script for creating the user. This is not clear from your question. I suggest that you either edit your question and ask a new one. Don't forget to show *how* you actually call your script, and the exact error message your receive.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to read the file and iterate over each line to create the users.

check it out:

```
#!/bin/bash

#specify the path to your CSV file
csv_file=/path/to/your_csv.csv

#iterate through each line in the CSV file
while IFS=, read -r user password
do
    adduser --quiet --disabled-password --shell /bin/bash --home /home/$user --gecos "User" $user
    echo "$user:$password" | chpasswd
    echo User: $user has been created with password: $password
done < "$csv_file"
```

as you see the `adduser` and `chpasswd` commands are then executed for each `user/password` combination, and if you have APIs to create users, you can use those instead of the `adduser` and `chpasswd` within the loop!

Comment: How do I use the API? Should I be just placing them in place of adduser and chpasswd?

Comment: @KarthikBhandary as I told if you have APIs to create users, you can use those instead of the adduser and chpasswd commands within the loop and you would need to replace those commands with the appropriate API calls to create users using the provided username and password!

Comment: ok understood. Thanks

Comment: I have this doubt. when I log in using my creds it shows gitea icon on the tab. So now should I be using this script or is it just something else?

Comment: @KarthikBhandary It's another question,but you see that because it suggests that you might be using Gitea, an open-source self-hosted Git service and the script I provided you earlier is a general example to create users using a CSV file and does not specifically integrate with Gitea,for that you would need to refer to the Gitea API documentation for the appropriate endpoints and parameters!

Comment: I have taken a look at the documentation and I have found the command to create a user but only for a single user.

Comment: I am not able to run the gitea command.